# How can I refresh the previews in Chrome's New Tab page?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using `Chrome 6.0.472.0 dev` and the New-Tab-feature. Some of my (sticky) previews were created in an "unlucky" moment, eg. [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) before I logged in

[image]

or [GMail](https://gmail.com) ... for whatever reason that preview is empty:

[image]

How can I force Chrome to refresh a particular preview?

Comment: Fail for using JPEG for screenshots.

Comment: indeed, it is the most important issue right now. it is absolutely unclear what the question is about without having the right .png screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there's an option to do this, but... the ugly way is:

Go to

`%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default`

and delete `Thumbnails` (no file extension), then visit each page on your new tab page. The path may be slightly different for operating systems other than Windows 7.

[courtesy of skier88](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=4a7b0b0a722d169f&hl=en)

Comment: This works only for older versions of Chrome. As of February 2013, there's no `Thumbnails` file any more.

Comment: In newer versions, the file is "Top Sites".  Deleting the file is probably not necessary, however.  If you "open in new tab" the thumbnail will not refresh.  You have to left-click and let the page load in the current tab to get a new thumbnail.

Answer (score 9):

One option is to go to the  `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` directory and delete the `Top Sites` file (if using Chrome 14; in older versions it was called `Thumbnails`), but that will remove also the other settings of the New Tab page.

A better option is to get [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) and reset only the thumbnail data. Download the SQLite binary, unpack it to the above mentioned directory, and run the following command:

```
sqlite3.exe "Top Sites" "update thumbnails set thumbnail=null"
```

After that the icons on the New Tab page will be broken, but they will be updated after you visit each of the pages once.

Comment: still works for Version 20.0.1123.1 dev

Comment: ...but not for version Version 23.0.1271.95 m...

Comment: Works for 24.0.1312.57 m