# Refresh "Most visited" pages previews

Tags: macos, google-chrome, thumbnails

On OS X 10.8 I'm using Chrome 23.0.1271.64, the latest version as of today. The "Most visited" page thumbnails show content which completely outdated since months, though I visited the pages in the mean-time. How to refresh the previews/thumbnails?

Comment: If you delete every thumbnail by hovering over it and clicking "x" on upper right of each one, it will say "thumbnail removed" Then it offer option to undo. Click "restore all" Does it work?

Comment: Already tried without reliable success. Sometimes it works, most often not.

Comment: for more reliable way does this work instead? http://lifehacker.com/5684600/refresh-google-chromes-most-visited-thumbnails

Comment: No, because there is no `Thumbnails` file.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but instead of Thumbnails file, what if you delete the file called "Top Sites" from that directory, works then? (from https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/V6GeKFoL_u4)

Comment: Well, after deleting the `Top Sites`, the complete "most visited" pages will be reset.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/166770/how-can-i-refresh-the-previews-in-chromes-new-tab-page/345500#345500

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the Windows version.  I figured out that the problem was that I was clicking all the tiles with the jog wheel to open them in eight new tabs.  That's very convenient, except Chrome only updates the site thumbnail when you left-click to open the shortcut in the current tab.

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete existing "Most visited" pages preview and they should be replaced with new ones which appear to be frequently used.

Comment: OP wanted to know how to update a thumbnail.  Clearing them is not the same thing.

Comment: Then why after deleting old thumbnails I get them replaced with new, which previously were not on the thumbnail page?